# я использую Camera2API, как поставить изображение в кадр?

Tags: java, android, камера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть такая, я хочу чтоб когда открывалась сессия просмотра, юзер на экране видел очертания формы человека. То есть, когда он включает камеру, чтоб на экране была картинка не только вывода изображения а и дополнительная прозрачная картинка в форме очертания(shape of body)...

Я так понимаю, что когда изображение выводиться нужно к нему прибавлять необходимую картинку и уже потом транслировать изображение на экран или возможно есть возможность транслировать изображение а на него наложить слой как бы сверху?

Вот мой код

```
public class CameraHelper {
private CameraCaptureSession mSession = null;
private CameraManager mCameraManager = null;
private CameraDevice mCameraDevice = null;
private String mCameraID = null;
private Context context;
private TextureView mTextureView;
private ImageReader imageReader;
private Handler handler;
private Surface jpegCaptureSurface;
private static ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream;


public CameraHelper(@NonNull CameraManager cameraManager, @NonNull String cameraID, Context context) {
    mCameraManager = cameraManager;
    mCameraID = cameraID;
    this.context = context;

    //нужно разобраться с этой строчкой, она 650 в коде
    handler = new Handler();
}

public static ByteArrayOutputStream getOutputStream() {
    return outputStream;
}

public void viewFormatSize(int formatSize) {

//      Получения характеристик камеры, Для получения характеристик необходимо
//      использовать метод getCameraCharacteristics(String cameraId). Этот метод возвращает объект
//      класса CameraCharacteristics, в котором сконцентрированы параметры по камере. В данном классе
//      сконцентрировано огромное количество параметров
    CameraCharacteristics cc;
    try {
        cc = mCameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraID);

        // Получения списка выходного формата, который поддерживает камера
        StreamConfigurationMap configurationMap =
                cc.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

        // Получения списка разрешений которые поддерживаются для формата jpeg
        Size[] sizesJPEG = new Size[0];
        if (configurationMap != null) {
            sizesJPEG = configurationMap.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        }

        if (sizesJPEG != null) {
            for (Size item : sizesJPEG) {
                System.out.println("w:" + item.getWidth() + " h:" + item.getHeight());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "camera with id: " + mCameraID + " don`t support format: " +
                    formatSize);
        }

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}

public boolean isOpen() {
    return mCameraDevice != null;
}

public void setTextureView(TextureView mImageView) {
    mTextureView = mImageView;
}

//    В методе openCamera() с помощью нашего менеджера открываем камеры. В параметрах метода
//    указываем, какую камеру открывать, а также обработчик, который будет отслеживать состояния
//    открытия камеры.
public void openCamera() {
    try {
//            я так понимаю что здесь мы проверяем прописан ли у нас доступ к камере в манифесте и
//            если все в порядке то выполняется открытие камеры
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        mCameraManager.openCamera(mCameraID, mCameraCallback, null);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void closeCamera() {

    if (mCameraDevice != null) {
        mCameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }
}

private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        mCameraDevice = camera;
        createCameraPreviewSession();
        System.out.println("----------" + mCameraDevice.getId());
        MainActivity.ToastPrint(mCameraDevice.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
        mCameraDevice.close();
        Log.i(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "disconnect camera  with id:" + mCameraDevice.getId());
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
        Log.i(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "error! camera id:" + camera.getId() + " error:" + error);
    }
};

private void createCameraPreviewSession() {

//        для получения изображения нам необходимо использовать  ImageReader. Для получения
//        максимально возможной скорости передачи кадров нам необходимо использовать «сырой формат». То
//        есть, jpeg нам не подойдет, поскольку он будет давать задержку на время конвертации кадра и
//        таким образом у нас возникнет очень низкий fps. Для получения максимальной продуктивности
//        следует использовать ImageFormat.YUV_420_888.
    imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(640, 480, ImageFormat.JPEG, 2);
    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, handler);

    //эти 2 строчки пока не понятно зачем нужны
    SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
    texture.setDefaultBufferSize(640, 480);
    Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

    try {
        final CaptureRequest.Builder builder =
                mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

//            builder.addTarget(jpegCaptureSurface);
        builder.addTarget(surface);

        //это добавление возможных эффектов
//            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_INCANDESCENT);
//            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE_SEPIA);
//            builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
//                    Collections.singletonList(imageReader.getSurface()),
                Collections.singletonList(surface),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        mSession = session;
                        try {
                            mSession.setRepeatingRequest(builder.build(), null, null);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    }
                },
                null
        );


    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener onImageAvailableListener =
        new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                final Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();

                jpegCaptureSurface = reader.getSurface();

//                    handler.post(new ImageSaver(context));
            }
        };
```

Comment: Сократите код. Наверняка многое там лишнее. Вам, возможно, нужно лишь в разметке вьюху сверху полупрозрачную положить и всё.

Comment: Я не могу сократить его так как не знаю, на каком этапе нужно будет добавить то, что я хочу... может вьюха такая и выручит, но какая тогда?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтоб в итоге получился эффект как, если знаете в приложениях в которых добавляют бороду или другие аксессуары к лицу человека. Когда допустим борода уже есть в кадре и ты наводишь кадр на лицо человека и делаешь снимок...

Comment: Ну, лично я с камерой дел никогда не имел. Если вью с камерой находится в контролируемое вами разметке, то вы можете поверх неё поместить картинку нужную и после получения снимка преобразовать его и картинку в BitMap и сложить их.

Comment: Хехе хороший совет сократите код)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно в `RelativeLayout` в котором находиться `TextureView` в которое будет устанавливаться наш вывод изображения с камеры, установиться еще один  `RelativeLayout` которому задать параметры

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

и как задний фон вложенного `RelativeLayout` установить наше изображение. Но естественно картинка которую будем устанавливать должна быть прозрачно, то есть без фона, просто очертания...

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/control"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/transparentImage">
```

в итоге получается так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

картинку можно поменять на нужную и она будет накладываться поверх изображения которое дает нам камера.